# Same CSS for two different layouts

Tags: html, css

Given an html page that can not be modified. The only access I have is CSS.
Page is loaded and displayed via an iframe from the other domain.

This is actually a payment gateway that either shows saved card OR shows the input fields to add a new card. To do so it uses the same input fields with same attributes. (Crazy, I agree)

So page may display 2 states:

1) form fields are preset: card is saved, values are not empty, select has an option selected. Saved card: https://jsfiddle.net/z0db0wL7/1/

2) form fields are empty/not set: values are empty and ready for input, select has **Select One** first option selected. New card: https://jsfiddle.net/j1b6fzc4/

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" .... >
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" class="firstname" name="FirstName" value="Test" required="">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" class="lastname" name="LastName" value="Test2" required="">
        <input type="text" id="cardnumber" class="cardnumber" name="CardNumber" value="" placeholder="Visa ending in 1111" required="">

        <select id="exp_month" class="exp_month" name="ExpirationMonth" required="">
            <option value="">&lt;Select One&gt;</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option selected>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
        </select>

        <select id="exp_year" class="exp_year" name="ExpirationYear" required="">
            <option value="">&lt;Select One&gt;</option>
            <option>2017</option>
            <option>2018</option>
            <option selected>2019</option>
            <option>2020</option>
            <option>2021</option>
            <option>2022</option>
            <option>2023</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</form>
```

All Classes/ID etc. are the same, the only difference is: empty values for the **input type="text"** and default (top) option is selected in the **select** element.

When the card is preset, I'm trying to pretend that there is no input elements behind (achieved).

When the card is not saved, style is changing back to normal. All works EXCEPT the **select** element, as I can not find the way of checking it.

Any ideas how to achieve that? Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Without the ability to change any of the HTML you are severely limited. If you had any way of adding a class to the `body` or any other wrapping tag you could leverage that. As CSS has no parent selector, you can't rely on the state change of the form elements to change anything "upstream" of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a combination of selectors. You want the `#exp_month` select to have the read-only look only when it has a value filled in (i.e. the user has made a selection), AND the `#cardnumber` input has its `value` attribute set (i.e. this is after a submit).
So the selector you need is

```css
#cardnumber:not([value='']) ~ .exp_month:valid
```

Then the empty form looks like

```css
.firstname, .lastname, .cardnumber, .exp_month, .exp_year {
 background-color:transparent;
 border:none!important;
 font-weight:400!important;
 pointer-events:none;
  display: block;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:#000;
}
#cardnumber:not([value='']) ~ #exp_month:valid,
#cardnumber:not([value='']) ~ #exp_year:valid {
 -moz-appearance:none;
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 text-indent:1px;
 text-overflow:'';
}
.mvp_exp_month::-ms-expand, .mvp_exp_year::-ms-expand {
 display:none;
}
input[value=''] {
 background-color:#fff!important;
 border: 1px solid #000!important;
 pointer-events:all!important;
}
input:placeholder-shown {
 background-color:transparent!important;
 border:none!important;
 pointer-events:none!important;
}

input, select {margin-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<form id="my_form" method="post" .... >
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" class="firstname" name="FirstName" value="" required="">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" class="lastname" name="LastName" value="" required="">
        <input type="text" id="cardnumber" class="cardnumber" name="CardNumber" value="" placeholder="Visa ending in 1111" required="">

        <select id="exp_month" class="exp_month" name="ExpirationMonth" required="">
            <option value="" selected>&lt;Select One&gt;</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
        </select>

        <select id="exp_year" class="exp_year" name="ExpirationYear" required="">
            <option value="" selected>&lt;Select One&gt;</option>
            <option>2017</option>
            <option>2018</option>
            <option>2019</option>
            <option>2020</option>
            <option>2021</option>
            <option>2022</option>
            <option>2023</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</form>
```

and the filled out form looks like this:

```css
.firstname, .lastname, .cardnumber, .exp_month, .exp_year {
 background-color:transparent;
 border:none!important;
 font-weight:400!important;
 pointer-events:none;
  display: block;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:#000;
}
#cardnumber:not([value='']) ~ #exp_month:valid,
#cardnumber:not([value='']) ~ #exp_year:valid {
 -moz-appearance:none;
 -webkit-appearance:none;
 text-indent:1px;
 text-overflow:'';
}
.mvp_exp_month::-ms-expand, .mvp_exp_year::-ms-expand {
 display:none;
}
input[value=''] {
 background-color:#fff!important;
 border: 1px solid #000!important;
 pointer-events:all!important;
}
input:placeholder-shown {
 background-color:transparent!important;
 border:none!important;
 pointer-events:none!important;
}

input, select {margin-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<form id="my_form" method="post" .... >
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" class="firstname" name="FirstName" value="Test" required="">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" class="lastname" name="LastName" value="Test2" required="">
        <input type="text" id="cardnumber" class="cardnumber" name="CardNumber" value="4444-3333-2222-1111" placeholder="Visa ending in 1111" required="">

        <select id="exp_month" class="exp_month" name="ExpirationMonth" required="">
            <option value="">&lt;Select One&gt;</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option selected>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
        </select>

        <select id="exp_year" class="exp_year" name="ExpirationYear" required="">
            <option value="">&lt;Select One&gt;</option>
            <option>2017</option>
            <option>2018</option>
            <option selected>2019</option>
            <option>2020</option>
            <option>2021</option>
            <option>2022</option>
            <option>2023</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</form>
```

(Note: identical, only with different values and selections)

---

As per the comments, the `~` trick can't always be used. When the input is in a different div than the select, they are no longer next to each other.
In that case, we can use the fact that the form itself can also get the `:valid` pseudo class if all the inputs in it are valid (see [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html#selector-valid)). You simply write

```css
#my_form:valid #exp_month:valid,
#my_form:valid #exp_year:valid {
```

instead.
On the downside, this does mean that the behaviour changes: it won't wait for a submit, but changes the appearance as soon as all the fields are filled out properly. Haven't found any workarounds for that yet.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. But if input elements are wrapped with, let's say div it's not going to work, right? As they're not siblings any more. Any solution for that case?

Comment: I mean separately wrapped. Each of the inputs is wrapped with div

Comment: @SuperUser7965880 Can't say. I would have to see the source!

Comment: You're right. Now you _can_ use the trick that filling out all fields makes the form itself valid, so you can write `#my_form:valid` for a selector. See edit. But see also the disclaimer about the downside.